# SublimeLinter - nodeca plugin

Tags: javascript, lint, sublimelinter

SublimeLinter stops linting when I try to use the ESLint plugin [Nodeca](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-nodeca)

Here's my .eslintrc:

`{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "node": true
    },
    "plugins":["nodeca"],
    "rules": {
        "quotes": 0,
        "no-underscore-dangle": 0,
        "no-path-concat": 0,
        "valid-jsdoc": 1,
        "no-reserved-keys": 1,
        "block-scoped-var": 1,
        "no-lonely-if": 1,
        "no-nested-ternary": 1,
        "no-multiple-empty-lines": 1,
        "space-after-keywords": [1, "always"],
        "space-before-blocks": [1, "always"],
        "nodeca/indent": [2, "spaces", 4]
    }
}`

I know it's just that plugin because it works when I comment these lines out

`"plugins":["nodeca"], 
"nodeca/indent": [2, "spaces", 4]`

Sublime console shows:

`SublimeLinter: eslint: Grunt.config.js ['/usr/local/bin/eslint', '--format=compact', '--stdin']`
`SublimeLinter: eslint output:`
`<text>: line 16, col 48, Error - Trailing comma. (no-comma-dangle)`
`1 problem`

**But** when I put those lines back in to use nodeca, the linter stops working and I get this in the console:

`SublimeLinter: eslint: Grunt.config.js ['/usr/local/bin/eslint', '--format=compact', '--stdin']`

I know the plugin is installed with node because I see it in my package.json and npm list.

I'm pretty new to front-end development, so any help you can give me would be appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, I just needed to install the node plugin globally:

`sudo npm install eslint-plugin-nodeca -g`